# How to add lib with jars to shared folder?

Tags: scala.js

I have a cross building scala-js project with a `client`, `server` and `shared` folder. If I add a `lib` folder with some jars in the `server` project folder I can reference the classes in the jars in my server code. But if add the `lib` folder in the `shared` project folder I can't reference the classes in my shared code. Can I add some command in my sbt build file to get my jars visible in my shared project or what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.jars should never be shared, since it is not the same .jar for Scala/JVM and Scala.js, even if they have the same source code.

If you have the two .jars for JVM and JS, you can put them in `shared/jvm/lib/` and `shared/js/lib/`, respectively.

(if you use `.crossType(CrossType.Pure)`, use `.jvm`/`.js` instead of `jvm`/`js`)

Comment: Ah, I see. This works perfectly, thank you! I thought I couldn't place anything there "manually". Thanks a ton for all your work with scala-js!