# Using an external jar in a Scala.js project

Tags: scala.js

I have a library in a jar that I would like to use in a Scala.js project.
Is any jar usable as a dependency of a Scala.js project?
Or should the jar have been compiled in a specific way?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the library, and exactly how you're trying to use it -- there are some macro libraries that work, for example, and you *can* technically put anything in a jar -- but usually this doesn't make sense. Jars are usually composed mainly of JVM classes, which aren't compatible with Scala.js' JavaScript environment.

This is really the biggest practical difference between ScalaJVM and Scala.js -- while the *language* is identical, the *libraries* are entirely separate...

Answer (score 1):

The jar must have been compiled by the Scala.js compiler, so that it contains the `.sjsir` files, necessary for compilation to JavaScript. If it was compiled by the regular Scala/JVM compiler, you will not be able to use it in a Scala.js project (unless it *only* contains macros).

See also [How to add lib with jars to shared folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46744383/1829647)